# Error using LocomotiveScroll: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inView')

Tags: javascript, locomotive-scroll

I'v been setting up [Locomotive scroll](https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll) on my site and suddenly got the following error and cant see or think I've done anything for this to happen. I'm struggling to work out the issue and any pointers would be great.

The function to add scrolled to the body has stopped working because of the error but Locomotive itself is still performing on the site
I have an old version of the site loaded on a browser window and it all works and I cant see the difference between that and few saves later.

```
locomotive-scroll.js?m=1683112609:2609 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inView')
    at locomotive-scroll.js?m=1683112609:2609:26
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at _default.addElements (locomotive-scroll.js?m=1683112609:2570:13)
    at _default.init (locomotive-scroll.js?m=1683112609:2127:14)
    at Smooth.init (locomotive-scroll.js?m=1683112609:3098:21)
    at new Smooth (locomotive-scroll.js?m=1683112609:3083:12)
    at loco.js?m=1683388185:1:16
(
```

My loco.js file looks like this:

```
const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
    el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
    smooth: true,
    // smoothMobile: true,
});

scroll.on('scroll', (position) => {
  if ((position.scroll.y) > 50) {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('scrolled');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('scrolled');
  }
});
```